# Make a square with letters

Tags: javascript, html, ascii-art

I have this:

```
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
ooooo
```

Put `o` on everything except the middle so it turns into this:

```
ooooo
o   o
o   o
o   o
ooooo
```

Is there anyway I can do that in Javascript?
My code currently is:
HTML:

```
<input type = 'text' id = 'box' placeholder = 'Enter n'  onkeyup = 'bigbox();'/>
        <br><br>

        <div id="output"></div>
```

Script:

```
 function bigbox() { 

            number = document.getElementById('box').value;
            display = document.getElementById("output");

        for(let j = 0; j<number; j++) {
            for(let i = 0; i<number; i++) 
            text += "o";
            text += "<br>";

            }


        display.innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Do you want it dynamic?

Comment: I have "this" how? please show also the markup.

Comment: Post ```HTML``` code as well..

Comment: @NiteshPhadare what does dynamic mean? And also what do you mean by markup

Comment: @Elliot  please specific. Do you want the highlight boundary letter in a given paragraph?

Comment: Hi Elliot. I would recommend if you learn how to refactor your code. Since this would be way easier to read if the tabs were correct.

Comment: Ok I will next time, I'm just used to coding as fast as possible since this is basic code I thought there's no need to indent to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add if one of the indices is zero or plus one equal to the wanted site of the square, then take a border character or space.

Basically this line

```
text += i === 0 || i + 1 === size || j === 0 || j + 1 === size ? "o": " ";
```

contains three parts:

1. An [addition assignment `+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment), which takes an expression and adds it to the left hand side variable.

   ```
   text += someExpression
   ```
2. A [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) which takes an expression and checks if this is [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (like any number except zero or `NaN`, any non empty string, an object or array, `true`) or [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (like zero/`NaN`, `''`, `null`, `undefined`, `false`).

   If *truthy*, it take the value after the `?` and if *falsy* the value after `:`.

   It is a kind of short form of an `if` statement with getting an expression.

   ```
   expression ? alternative1 : alternative2 // code
   truthy   ->  alternative1                // result
   falsy    ->                 alternative2
   ```
3. A condition part. The conditions are a connected with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), this returns the first *truthy* value, or the last *falsy* one.

   ```
   condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || ...
   ```

   The conditions check the indices and if zero or the greatest valid value, then you hit a border, otherwise you are inside of the square.

```js
function bigbox(size) {
    var display = document.getElementById("output"),
        text = "";

    size = +size;
    for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            text += i === 0 || i + 1 === size || j === 0 || j + 1 === size ? "o": " ";
        }
        text += "<br>";
    }
    display.innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box" onchange="bigbox(this.value)">
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: For security reason, it's better to use `innerText`, you can replace `<br>` by `\n`

Comment: You're very smart, can you explain what does the line  text += i === 0 || i + 1 === size || j === 0 || j + 1 === size ? "o": " "; do so I understand how it works? I didn't learn the ? and the :

Comment: @Elliot `x = a ? b : c` is the same as `if (a) { x = b } else { x = c }`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add a little logic to determine whether a `o` or a space should be output.

Essentially, an `o` should be output if:

- It's the first or last row, or
- it's the first or last column.

See the below example snippet:

```js
function bigbox() { 
  number = document.getElementById('box').value;
  display = document.getElementById("output");
  var text = '';
  
  for(let j = 0; j < number; j++) {
    for(let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      if (j == 0 || j == number - 1 || i == 0 || i == number - 1) {
        text += "o";
      } else {
        text += '&nbsp;';
      }
    }
    text += "<br>";
  }
  display.innerHTML = text;
}

bigbox();
```

```css
#output {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Typewriter", monospace;
}
```

```html
<input id="box" value="5" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bigbox() { 

        number = document.getElementById('box').value;
        display = document.getElementById("output");
    text="";
    for(let j = 0; j<number; j++) {
        for(let i = 0; i<number; i++)
        if(j != 0 && j != number - 1)
            if(i==0)
                    text += "o";
            else if(i == number-1){
                text += "o";
                text += "<br/>";
            }else
            text += "&nbsp;&nbsp;"
        else{
            text += "o";
        }
        text += "<br/>";            

        }

    display.style.lineHeight = 0.5;
    display.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put that middle part in a  tag and do the styling to that tag.

Comment: You should clarify, your answer is not well explained

Comment: But it's in a script, I can't put a tag in a script